# How to allow only one view in navigation stack to rotate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, autorotate

I have ViewControllers A and B on the navigation stack.  A does not support landscape orientation, B does.  If the user rotates to landscape while viewing B and then taps the Back button, A is now in landscape.  How do I prevent this?  Is there a good reason the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method of A is not respected?

Comment: I don't get why Cocoa Touch goes to all those lengths with all the autorotate business, but then fails to account for this simple and very common situation. +1 for putting this out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really very annoying thing about view controllers. And It seems to be no fix for autorotation. Maybe, the best would be return NO from B's  shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation   and  then perform view rotation manually. Then it won't affect A.

Comment: Pulling my hair out! How do you manually force change of orientation? The problem is that I need to have actual change of orientation so the keyboard shows from the right spot.

Answer (score 1):

yes, i hate that too...
all i found to solve it was to do it by myself:

```
- (void)myAutomaticRotation{
    if (A.view.frame.size.width > A.view.frame.size.height) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5f];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f);
        A.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320, 480);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

you can call myAutomaticRotation in a main/super UIViewController when you navigate to A.view,
and in that same place you should use:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

}
```

where you can check the view used (A,B) and allowing landscape mode just for B...

luca

Comment: Thanks for the code here. I think Max's suggestion of handling rotation separately in each viewController is a little cleaner.